# Images in PDFs with pug, node and headless chrome

Tags: pug, puppeteer

Using `puppeteer` or `html-pdf-chrome` with `pug` templates in `NodeJS` to generate PDFs, how can I print images?

When I use an image tag pointing to the image locally, the image is broken in the rendered PDF.

The only way I could find is to base64 images and use those in the pug templates.

Is there a way to tell `puppeteer` or `html-pdf-chrome` to insert the images in the html before printing to PDF?